# How to order a collection.find based on an external api call result?

Tags: meteor

I have a collection named events. They're geolocalized.
I want to show a list of events to the client ordered by the distance between the client and each event (by road). To calculate this, I use a HTTP.call to the open mapquest api wrapped in a meteor method.

I can't find a good way to order the results for the client and keep the reactivity (showing new events automatically).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'observe' your events collection and create a new client side only collection (or alter the events collection) that has a 'distanceFromClient" field and then you can sort by this.

```
    Events = new Meteor.Collection('events');


    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      GeoEvents = new Meteor.Collection(null);

      var eventsObserver = Events.find().observe({
            added: function(item) {
              item.distanceFromUser = distanceFrom(item);
              GeoEvents.insert(item);
            }
          });

      Template.myTemplate.helpers({
        events: function() {      
          return GeoEvents.find({},{sort: {distanceFromUser: 1});
        }
      });
   }
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea. Could you throw a code example ? I'm new to Meteor.

Comment: Thanks ! It works great. Would you mind telling me how I can alter the client's event collection instead of creating an other one ?